# Format multiple python variables

Tags: python

I'm early in the learning stages of python, and I've spent the last hour or so trying to find a more efficient way to format multiple integer variables to have thousands separators. This method works, but I can't shake the feeling that if you're doing the same thing 4 times, there is probably a better way to do it.

```
if check > 999:
 check = "{:,}".format(check)
if number > 999:
 number = "{:,}".format(number)
if nmod > 999:
 nmod = "{:,}".format(nmod)
if ndiv > 999:
 ndiv = "{:,}".format(ndiv)
```

Thanks in advance!
-Rali

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically what you want to do is perform the same operation on a group of elements. This will require for you to know about lists/tuples and the use/definition of functions. 
One of the simplest way to solve this is to implement a function that does this for you for any amount of arguments you are going to pass to it by using (*args).

```
def format_check( *args):
    res = []
    for arg in args:
        res.append( '{:,}'.format(arg))

    return res

a = 123123
b = 153452
c = 567567
d = 1233
e = 12

a,b,c,d,e = format_check( a,b,c,d,e)

print( a,b,c,d,e, sep='\n')
```

which will output

```
123,123
153,452
567,567
1,233
12
```

A more elaborated, but much more compact way would be:

```
a,b,c,d,e = map( lambda x: '{:,}'.format(x), (a,b,c,d,e))
```

For this you will need to learn about the use of map, which applies a function to all element of an iterable object and lambda which lets you define a quick oneline nameless function.

```
lambda x: '{:,}'.format(x)
```

is kinda equivalent to

```
def some_function( x):
    return '{:,}'.format(x)
```

Comment: Thanks Crivella! I definitely need to learn more about lists, tuples, and functions. I very much appreciate the examples and explanations.

Answer (score 0):

You could also store your variables in a [`list`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html), then [`map()`](http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/map_filter.html#map) them with a [`lambda`](http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/lambdas.html#lambdas).

```
change = lambda s: [s, '{:,}'.format(s)][s > 999]
```

That lambda will act like a function (and you can define it using a function `def` as well) but lambdas are shorter. It can be passed one (positional) argument, and it returns `s` if `s > 999` is false (i.e. `0`) or `'{:,}'.format(s)` when `s > 999` is true (i.e. 1). You're basically accessing a list, indexing it whether or not `s > 999`.

What's great about a lambda/function is that you can keep the repetitive code all in one place.

You can then use a `map()` like so

```
vars = [check, number, nmod, ndiv]
vars[:] = map(change, vars)     # modifies the list in-place

newList = [*map(change, vars)]  # creates a new list
```

The `map()` will apply the `change` lambda (or function) onto each variable and return a *generator* with the results.

```
check, number, nmod, ndiv = 2000, 3000, 400

# lambda
change = lambda s: [s, '{:,}'.format(s)][s > 999]

# list
vars = [check, number, nmod, ndiv]

# before
print(vars)

# map in-place
vars[:] = map(change, vars)

# after
print(vars)
```

Output:

```
[1000, 2000, 3000, 4000]
['1,000', '2,000', '3,000', '4,000']
```

Comment: Thank you TrebuchetMS! I really appreciate the explanation. I went through a tutorial that discussed lambda, but didn't quite understand it without a use case. This is the first I've heard of map, so I'll read up on it.

Comment: I guess my answer might've been a bit of an overkill for your problem but hey, at least it introduces you to lambdas and maps. :-)

Comment: Not at all an overkill in my opinion! I am a python information sponge right now and appreciate every bit of help I can get! Thanks again!